# Get the iframe src without using getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can pass the iframe src into a variable without using `getElementById` ?

I dont know the ID of the iframe as its dynamically generated - but I want to be able to check the src to see if it matches a defined string - the iframe has a class which I can target which is **fancybox-iframe**

I was hoping this would work but it does not:

```
 var srcURL = document.getElementsByClassName('fancybox-iframe').src;
```

Comment: How about `srcURL = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src;` ?

Comment: `$("iframe.fancybox-iframe").attr("src")` (as tagged [tag:jquery]) and assuming you only have one iframe with that class

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, which is why `.src` doesn't work.

Comment: i have more than one iframe on the page ...

Comment: "*i have more than one iframe on the page*" - more than one with that class?  If so, how do you know which one you want?  Or do you want all of them (eg in an array)?

Comment: @freedomn-m your code works - just one iframe with that class name. Others suggesteing selecting just the iframe element which wont work as more than one on the page - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `getgetElementsByTagName()`:

```
srcURL = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src;
```

Take care the name of this method is written in plural form so the result is an array, even the array will contain one element. That's why the argument `[0]` is appended.

Answer (score 0):

```
Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName
```

returns an array of elements, so you should use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fancybox-iframe')[0].src
```

or better yet

```
const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('fancybox-iframe'))
  .filter(element => element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'iframe');

if(!elements.length) {
  // handle no iframe.fancybox-iframe found
}

const src = elements[0].src
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName

Also you can use [`Element.prototype.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [`Element.prototype.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to avoid filtering the `getElementsByClassName` result and get directly the iframes as so

```
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('iframe.fancybox-iframe'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed in the comments:

- there's multiple `iframe`s
- only one has the class `fancybox-iframe`
- jquery is already in use

You can select an iframe with a specific class using

```
$("iframe.fancybox-iframe")
```

then apply `.attr("src")` to get the source:

```
$("iframe.fancybox-iframe").attr("src")
```

This is in the format of `nodename.class` (without any spaces) which means the element must be of node type (iframe) *and* have the class (fancybox-iframe).

You could probably also use

```
$(".fancybox-iframe").attr("src")
```

if that class is only used on that iframe.